# Nginx with arbitrary url in sub-directory serving same content

Tags: nginx

As an example, I'd like to serve example.com/public/anyUserName , where anyUserName is a any combination of characters apart from path separators, from the /webapps/client directory. So, a query to example.com/public/Alice and a query to example.com/public/Bob will be served from the same directory. I should be able to request files such as  example.com/public/Alice/css/bootstrap.css  or http://example.com/public/Alice/client.js  without issue. Basically, I want to drop the username part of the url and serve from the same directory but I need to maintain the username in the browser's url.

I've tried many different config tweaks from a regex in the location to this monstrosity but I in every case I get a 404, a 500 which the logs say is a rewrite or internal redirection cycle, a 200 on every resource but each one is the index, or a 200 on every resource but each **except** the index is a 404.

```
    location /public  {
            index collmanagerclient.html;
            alias /webapps/client;
            autoindex on;
            try_files $2/$3/$4/$5/$6 $2/$3/$4/$5/$6/ =404;
    }
```

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name secure.example.me;
rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;

}
server {
listen 443;
server_name secure.example.me;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-unified.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1;
root /webapps/client;

index collmanagerclient.html;
location = / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}


location ~ /public/(?:[^/]+)/(?<filename>.+) {
 alias /webapps/client;

 rewrite ^ $filename last;
}


location /signup {
    index collmanagersignup.html;
    alias /webapps/signup;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /api {
    #turn gzip off to avoid breaking the cpu

    gzip off;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:7801;
    proxy_buffering off;

    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

}

Thanks, I've been driven insane over the last little while by this.

Comment: It is unclear to me, what exactly is your question. I understood your question the same way as Gmck, that is, you want to serve the same resource to everyone. Please give a concrete example, what URLs you want to use, and what files they should serve from what directories.

Comment: I changed to a concrete example rather than the previous poor one.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you need to look into the rewrite module. [Nginx Rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

Something like:

location /public {
    rewrite ^ /Foo last;
}

Comment: That results in the scenario I mentioned where I have everything as a 200 but I always have the same resource being returned. I need to essentially turn /public/* into / what I serve on root and that method only lets me serve one item for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one does what you want:

```
location ~ ^/public/(?:[^/]+)/(?<filename>.+)/?$ {
    alias /webapps/client;

    rewrite ^ $filename last;
}
```

And then, use this to replace `location = /` block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Here we use regular expressions to first match URIs like /public/username/file_to_get.html.

The first part between `/` characters captures the username, and stores it nowhere (`?:` modifier).

The second part captures the actual wanted filename to `$filename` variable.

Then we simply rewrite the request URI to the captured filename.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for but for some reason it doesn't work. I get an error of '2014/08/02 13:32:02 [error] 2528#0: *1335 open() "/webapps/client/public/Foo" f$' when querying /public/Foo which makes it seem like nginx is ignoring alias.

Comment: How does your complete nginx configuration look? There could be some other directives that take precedence to this block.

Comment: I added my config; I thought that probably wouldn't be an issue but then again, I'm a novice. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Please try the new version in my answer, I added start and end matching to the `location` directive.

Comment: `/webapps/client/public/Everlag/collmanagerclient.html is not found (2: No such file or directory)`  is the new error when the url is secure.example.me/public/Everlag/ (Notice the trailing slash) and the same error as before is still there for the non-slash terminated url.

Comment: See my revised answer. I added a better main location block, and I fixed the regex to ignore trailing slashes in directories, so that it won't try to use the file in `index` directive.

Comment: Curious, now I just get a 404 with nothing in the error log for both the slash and non-slash terminated urls. I tried commenting out the regex based /public/... block and then just hard coding /public/Everlag with alias and try_files to make absolutely certain it wasn't part of my external setup and it worked perfectly.